# How to reinstall the default desktop environment LXDE in LUBUNTU?

Tags: apt, lubuntu, xfce, lxde

I was trying out xfce in my Lubuntu 16.04 PC. I installed it, used it for a while and liked it. So, I thought I can remove LXDE and use only Xfce. I used some commands I found in the web and I ended up losing some packages of LXDE, but I couldn't remove them all. I also searched software centre for LXDE and removed some packages containing the name lxde. (but not all).

After using xfce for some time I realised that it was slower than LXDE. So I logged into LXDE and uninstalled xubuntu-desktop via command line. Now some packages in LXDE are missing like the package for changing desktop settings and the app for checking for updates. I don't know how many packages I removed from LXDE. sudo apt-get install -f does not  show any errors. 
**What I want is to completely reinstall LXDE (using alt+F1 screen) and reset LXDE settings to default values**. How do I do it?
Is sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop enough for reinstall?

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop` ?

Comment: Will I get back all the default applications?.(I dont need Abi word and gnumneric anyway)

Comment: Yes, this reinstall the whole lubuntu desktop, not just lxde and also take in to account that you have some of it installed already.

Comment: Better is `apt-get remove --purge lubuntu-desktop`, after that, `sudo apt --no-install-recommends install lubuntu-desktop`. It will not install these additional software

Comment: @Redbob No, that won't work `lubuntu-desktop` is a meta packge that refers to the other packages that make up lubuntu, you cannot purge it in that way and no-install-recs won't work either for the same reason.

Comment: I used sudo apt install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop and I think I got everything back. Now going to uninstall abiword and gnumeric.  Is it enough to undo whatever I did to LXDE? Should I do anything like resetting LXDE settings?

Comment: I can't tell you if the settings reverted or not as I can't see your PC. Have a look around and see but anything you removed is back, just like a first install.

Comment: The panel settings haven't changed. It is the same as before messing up with LXDE. Thanks a lot. I don't know whether I should reset it because I did some bad things to LXDE. Is it OK to continue like this?

Comment: No worries, if I answer, please accept, so this is removed from the unanswerd question list.

Comment: If you want to reset user config defaults, just rename `~/.config` folder. Don't delete it, because you may revert changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get back all the parts LXDE/Lubuntu you had removed, you can perform a reinstall with this command

```
sudo apt install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop
```

This will reinstall all the parts of the default Lubuntu desktop.